# Dúvida com geração de projeto ionic

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, ionic

Eu tenho este ambiente instalado:

> Nodejs = node-v6.9.1-x86.msi
>
> npm = 3.10.8
>
> jdk = jdk1.8.0_91
>
> cordova = 6.4.0
>
> ionic = 2.1.13

Ao entra no cmd como administrador, eu solicitei a criação de um projeto forçando a verão ionic 2, observei que a estrutura de pasta é diferente e a extensão dos arquivos e ”ts”, como eu poderia ter a versão em “js”?

```
 ionic start nomeAplicacao tabs --v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar o ionic-cli comandos; start, generate no Ionic 2 não é possível gerar .js, somente .ts.

Opções:

1. Usar Ionic 1.x `ionic start todo blank` Omite argumento `--v2` [Ionic 1 Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html)
2. Construir seu próprio workflow.

Os primeiros releases beta do Ionic 2 tinha o argumento `no-ts` no comando `start` mas foi removido. [Fonte](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-site/commit/83175e663f1a0293445a5523bc4b4f61ea7d0458)
Até onde eu sei o time está com todos os esforços e foco no TypeScript. Disponibilizando somente a criação dos arquivos com extensão TypeScript. [Fonte](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6964#issuecomment-226995975)

Comment: Eu não gostaria de usar o TypeScript, está é minha dúvida

Comment: Penso que a melhor opção então seja o v1 mesmo. Já q é com angular 1.x e tal